# rails named routes + controller as parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, named-routing

is it possible to have the controller value in a rails named route as a parameter, which I can pass at runtime to direct the call to the proper controller?

e.g.
map.ride 'ride' ,:controller => {some-way-of-specifying-a-parameter}, :action => 'ride'

then at runtime, I want to pass the controller name to which this call should be going. My actions are doing different things depending to which controller the call gets sent.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Thomas'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/110825/tomas-markauskas) answer is correct, however if you want more flexibility in the URL format you can specify multiple routes and use [route requirements](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-requirements) by putting `:requirements` on each. The route will only match if the requirements are met. For example:

```
map.resources :rides, :path_prefix => '/:option', 
  :requirements => { :option => /one/ }, :controller => 'one'
map.resources :rides, :path_prefix => '/:option', 
  :requirements => { :option => /two/ }, :controller => 'two'
```

and then:

`/one/rides` will go to `OneController`

`/two/rides` will go to `TwoController`

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
map.ride 'ride/:controller', :action => 'ride'
```

`/ride/first` would call `FirstController#ride` and `/ride/second` would call `SecondController#ride`

Comment: thanks Tomas - however, how would I specify the name of the controller? using the above I would normally get the ride_path available to me, and I would want to do something like ride_path(:controller => 'first') . would that work?

Comment: not to worry, i have figured it out, thanks a lot, thats what i wanted